# Correct use of array brackets

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, formal-languages

I am adding multiple languages to my custom **CMS**. I'm trying to have multiple language titles of the articles, based on the POSTed Language ID `[language_id]`. The `$title_[$lid]` should SET into DB's field `a_title_[$lid]`. I don't think I'm using `a_title_[$lid]` correctly. I would be immensely appreciative for any prompt help. I'm stuck in the water and under the gun.

```
$aid                = trim(cleanQuery($_POST[article_id]));
$lid                = trim(cleanQuery($_POST[language_id]));    
$title_[$lid]        = trim(cleanQuery($_POST[title_][$lid]));

mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET a_title_[$lid] ='$title_[$lid]' WHERE aid='$aid'");
```

Comment: `a_title_[$lid]` - a field name!!!!

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (quoting literal keys) and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double (interpolation with `{}` curly syntax). Also rather curb the `cleanQuery()` compost and read up on [parameterization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks b0s3. I realize a_title_[$lid] is not correct. Is there a better way to add the $lid variable to the a_title_ ?  I know I'm just asking for a fix, and should be doing more background on this, but when I say I'm under the gun, I am really under the gun. I will do the homework when this hurdle is crossed. I swear. I always do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't want to use arrays but dynamic variables names. So if you want to have variables $title_1, $title_2, $title_3. You need to use `{}` like that:

```
${'title_' . $lid} = trim(cleanQuery($_POST['title_'][$lid])); // or maybe trim(cleanQuery($_POST['title_' . $lid]));
```

And your query should look like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET a_title_$lid ='${'title_' . $lid}' WHERE aid='$aid'");
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks mate! (now on to coffee, then studying up my PHP/Array manual.)